# xxxxBundle\Entity\BookPermit object not found. (404 Not Found) - symfony

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony

I have a table that is related as shown in the diagram below.

bookpermit

```
id | userfk  | bookfk   |
1  | 6       | 6        |
2  | 6       | 7        |
3  | 7       | 7        |
4  | 8       | 8        |
```

books

```
id | name  | uerfk   |
1  | xyz1   | 6       |
2  | xyz2   | 7       |
3  | xyz3   | 8       |
```

user

```
id | email | phone |
6  | xyz   | xyz   |
7  | xyz   | xyz   |
8  | xyz   | xyz   |
```

Now I want to fetch results of books where it finds the corresponding parameter from the users table and the bookpermit table. The books table is related to the users table with a foreign key. The bookpermit table is related with a foreign key to the books table.

Here is the snippet of code for book permit

```
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="usersfk", type="integer")
     */
    private $usersfk;

                //getters and setters apply


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="permitid", type="integer")
     */
    private $permitid;

                //getters and setters apply



    // +++++++++++++++++1 relationship mapping between BookPermit and Users ++++++++++++++++++++ //
    //weak enity: book_permit can belong to different users
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="book_permit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usersfk", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userspermit;


    /**
     * Set Users
     *
     * @param \xxxBundle\Entity\Users $userspermit 
     * @return 
     */
    public function setUsersPermit(\xxxxBundle\Entity\Users $userspermit = null)
    {
        $this->userspermit = $userspermit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Users
     *
     * @return \xxxxBundle\Entity\Users
     */
    public function getUsersPermit()
    {
        return $this->userspermit;
    }





    // +++++++++++++++++1 relationship mapping between BookPermit and Books ++++++++++++++++++++ //
    //weak enity: bookpermit can belong to different books
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="bookpermit", inversedBy="book_book_permit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bookfk", referencedColumnName="usersfk")
     */
    private $bookpermit;


    /**
     * Set Books
     *
     * @param \xxxxBundle\Entity\Books $bookpermit 
     * @return 
     */
        public function setBookPermit(\xxxBundle\Entity\Books $bookpermit = null)
    {
        $this->bookpermit = $bookpermit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Books
     *
     * @return \xxxxBundle\Entity\Books
     */
    public function getBooksPermit()
    {
        return $this->bookpermit;
    }
```

Here is the snippet of code for books entity

```
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="usersfk", type="integer")
     */
    private $usersfk;

    //getters and setters apply here


// +++++++++++++++++1 relationship mapping between Books and Users ++++++++++++++++++++ //
    //weak enity: many books can belong to a user
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="books")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usersfk", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $users;


    /**
     * Set Users
     *
     * @param \xxxxBundle\Entity\Users $users 
     * @return 
     */
    public function setUsers(\xxxxBundle\Entity\Users $users = null)
    {
        $this->users = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Users
     *
     * @return \xxxxBundle\Entity\Users
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }


    // +++++++++++++++++1 relationship mapping between Books and  BookPermit ++++++++++++++++++++ //
    // 
    //super entity: one user can have different book 
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=BookPermit", mappedBy="bookpermit")
     */
    private $book_book_permit;

    /**
     * Add BookPermit
     *
     * @param \xxxxBundle\Entity\BookPermit $book_book_permit
     * @return BookPermit
     */
    public function addUserBookPermit(\xxxxBundle\Entity\BookPermit $book_book_permit)
    {
        $this->book_book_permit[] = $book_book_permit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove BookPermit
     *
     * @param \xxxxBundle\Entity\BookPermit $book_book_permit
     */
    public function removeUserBookPermit(\xxxxxBundle\Entity\BookPermit $book_book_permit)
    {
        $this->book_book_permit->removeElement($book_book_permit);
    }

    /**
     * Get BookPermit
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUserBookPermit()
    {
        return $this->book_book_permit;
    }
```

In my controller I am making this attempt that returns an object not found error

```
public function displayAction(Request $request, Users $user, BookPermit $bookpermit)
    {

    $bookLists= $em->getRepository("xxxBundle:Books")->findBy(
        array(
            "usersfk" => $user,
            "usersfk" => $bookpermit
        )
    );


    }
```

On calling the above controller it returns >>> xxxxBundle\Entity\BookPermit object not found. (404 Not Found).

What could be wrong with my approach

Comment: dump $bookpermit and see the id number, then try to search this id in your database.

Comment: @habibun I am encoding the response as a json. How do I dump it please. New to symfony

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: var_dump($bookpermit ); Still having thesame error

Comment: after var_dump exit, the script by using http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: var_dump($bookpermit );
    exit(1); I have this in my controller. But still having thesame error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161192/discussion-between-habibun-and-float).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Type Hinting from Action

instead of this

```
public function displayAction(Request $request, Users $user, BookPermit $bookpermit)
```

change to

```
public function displayAction(Request $request, $user, $bookpermit)
```